# phpmyadmin error, cannot click anything in the browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

my phpmyadmin error, can't click anything inside the browser. 
can't click on table name, can't click on database button, anything.

i try to inspect it.
this is what i got.

[image: pma error]

[image]

can someone help me to repair it?
i really don't have any idea what happen.

Comment: Have you tried to reload the page??
And have you tried in other browser to check if it is browser problem or the `phpmyadmin` problem.

Comment: @Siraj I have try other browser and reload, same result

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the phpmyadmin. Do you have backup of your databases?? If yes then reinstall your phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I was unable to perform any action via phpmyadmin. I switched from chrome to firefox and it started working perfectly. After this I cleared my cookies for localhost from chrome, & it started working for chrome as well.

Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.30
PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring
PHP version: 7.4.30

Answer (score 0):

Just restart Apache -  apachectl restart - works now on Safari too! March 2023.